log4j:ERROR log4j.appender.@log.appender@
I have a problem with log4j and it is weird that I didn't changed anything in code from when i left the work to when i arrived at work agian, and this error pop up
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.@log.appender@
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "@log.appender@".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

It is weird that it seems not to be connected to properties files and i dont remember to ever use anything related to @log.appender@. Maybe Tomcat changed something and broke some files?
I tried to go back to the last commit version to know exactly I am on the version that work but nothing changed as it still gives me the error.
I also run the Tomcat on service microservice with clean, install, and then on the web project run the tomcat but still nothing changed.
UPDATE: It seems that in applicationContext.xml the IntelliJ can't find the URL "http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" but don't understand why.
I work on Intellij. Grateful for any idea. Thank you!

Can you edit your question and add you log4j.properties file to it? @log.appender@ looks like a value that should be interpolated by your build tool. What build tool are you using? Maven?
